# RapidXML (C++): Accessing text within node but outside child-node

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, rapidxml

XML:

```
<node> 
    Lorem ipsum 
        <child-node>dolor</child-node>
    TEXT TO BE ACCESSED 
</node>

<node> 
    sed do eiusmod tempor etc. 
</node>
```

This is read into an `rapidxml::xml_document<>` and parsed with the flag `rapidxml::parse_validate_closing_tags` as follows: `doc.parse<rapidxml::parse_validate_closing_tags>()`. (I would have thought that this flag solved the issue, but this does not appear to be the case.)

RapidXML C++ code looping through all `<node>`s of `doc`:

```
for (const rapidxml::xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node("node"); node != nullptr;  node = node->next_sibling()) {
std::cout << node->value();
}
```

`node->value()` returns *Lorem ipsum* during the first loop.

While the text within the `<child-node>` (*dolor*) is accessible by creating a new `*node_2 = node->first_child()` (within the loop) and then accessing the value with `node_2->value()`, the text that *follows* the `<child node>` (*TEXT TO BE ACCESSED*) is not accessible in a similar way. The [documentation](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1accessing_dom_tree) does not offer much in terms of advice. How might this be done with RapidXML?

The XML is intended to encode an edition of a text (following e.g. [Perseus Digital Library](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/)) and so the format used above is useful in order to mark specific words within sentences etc.

Comment: It seems that treating the remainder of the node as a child node (`child_node->next_sibling()`) solves the issue, albeit in an inelegant manner, as the element marked as a child is then not distinguished automatically from the text not thus marked. This therefore amounts to ignoring the inner tags.

Answer (score 0):

RapidXML parses XML into nodes of different types, in particular `node_element` and `node_data` nodes. For example, your `<child-node>dolor</child-node>` is actually a `node_element` node which contains a `node_data` with the value "dolor".

To make user code simpler, getting the `value()` of a `node_element` returns the value of it's first data node - but if you have complex markup you can iterate over the data nodes to extract those values.

Untested code below

```
for (const rapidxml::xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node("node"); node; node = node->next_sibling())
{
  for (const rapidxml::xml_node<> *n= node.first_node(); n; n= n->next_sibling())
  if (n->type() == rapidxml::node_element)
  {
    // handle child-node
  }  
  else if (n->type() == rapidxml::node_data)
    std::cout << n->value(); // handle the regular data nodes
}
```